# SQL Server Agent Job Monitoring (did a Job even start?)

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, sql-agent-job

I am a BI developer and was entrusted with a task of a DBA. It's about monitoring SQL Server Agent jobs respectively getting information about the following key figures, which are to be prepared after all frontend:

1. Failed Server Agent Jobs and Jobsteps
2. Run-time of jobs and Jobsteps
3. Find out if a job has even started
4. Memory allocation: evaluation and monitoring of the moving and stored data volumes

The goal is to monitor and, if necessary, provide an indication of any discrepancies in the key figures.

I got the first two points. In each case I show in a table whether a job or whether steps are enabled/disabled. I have also recorded the terms of each step and thresholds can be used to warn if critical ranges are reached.

The biggest problems for me are the jobs that did not even start (Point 3.). To my knowledge, these are not recorded in the MSDB tables. I would like to know when a job or jobstep has not even started. Can you tell me how to get this info? Maybe someone already has a suitable script for this problem ready?

On the subject of memory usage, I'm interested in how much free space is left on the hard disk, how big the partition is and how the consumption changes over time.

On the internet, I could find nothing to the points 3rd and 4th. I would be very grateful for your help! (and forgive me my bad english :) )

Comment: How would you determine a job is supposed to have started, but did not? When you figure that out it's also possible to write a query for it (using `msdb.dbo.sysjobs`/`sysjobhistory`), but that's the tricky bit.

Comment: The job is set by a schedule, for example, so that it runs once a week.
It could be derived from the msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity table, but some information is missing.

Comment: SELECT
sj.name,
sj.job_id,
sja.session_id,
sja.run_requested_date,
sja.start_execution_date,
sja.stop_execution_date,
sja.next_sheduled_run_date
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
RIGHT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
ON sj.job_id = sja.job_id
WHERE sja.job_id = 'xy'
ORDER BY sja.session_id desc

Comment: You can use `sysschedules`/`sysjobschedules` to derive the job schedule (using a numbers table) but the format of this is not exactly convenient. Personally, I don't think I'd go so far as to sanity check if SQL Server Agent knows how to run schedules -- I'd assume it does. I'd limit myself to verifying it's actually running and (for critical jobs) derive some criteria to check if it worked completely outside of SQL Server Agent and the jobs. For example, I don't care if the Important Data Import Job *thinks* it ran successfully, I care if the data is there, so I'll check that instead.

Comment: [See also](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/148321/97345). In fact, in retrospect this entire question is a better fit for dba.SE, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I get as a result, when the next run of Job xy is planned. He does not appear in the table.
However, he appears on the SQL Server Agent in the job history. There, however, the information is missing when he should run the next time.
My plan was to take the next_scheduled_run_date column from the sysjobactivity table and then compare a run later to the run_requested_Date column.
But obviously some records are missing in the sysjobactivity table. The other table, which otherwise contains target_start times, is the sysjobschedules.
Unfortunately, this only has the currently scheduled date. I have not found another table that contains a history of the target run_dates.
Of course, one could have manual tables (analogous to the target values) but that would be too much effort.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, so don't post it as one. You can always [edit] your question with more information if it won't fit a comment.